# Response.Redirect from one web project to another in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, redirect

I am attempting to integrate a project into a pre-existing solution.

The start-up project in the solution is named "Foo." It is written to the virtual path "/csweb/." When this project starts up it loads /csweb/Default.aspx. This is the current, unmodified home page.

I am attempting to redirect to a different home page in a different project.

I  added a second project to the solution named "Bar." Under its project properties I told it to write to the virtual path "/csweb/." It is not marked as the start-up project, nor are there multiple start-up projects -- just Foo. Bar's homepage is accessible when Bar is marked as the start-up project. It's homepage is represented by localhost:port/csweb/Default.aspx

I would like to redirect to Bar's Default.aspx while using Foo as the start-up project. I am fine with renaming Bar's Default.aspx to something non-ambiguous, if that would make the problem easier.

If I try `HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")` then it clearly takes me to Foo/Default.aspx and not Bar/Default.aspx, but the url in the browser is just `localhost:port/csweb/Default.aspx`. There is no indication of being inside of a project, completely understandable. If I rename Bar/Default.aspx to Bar/UniqueName.aspx and attempt `HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/UniqueName.aspx")` then the page is not found.

What's the right call here? Do I need to setup Bar as a pre-existing virtual directory in IIS so that I can specify a more complete path name to avoid ambiguity? Or do I need to do something fancy with multiple start-up web projects in order for it to be accessible?

Thanks for any advice on this confusing issue.

EDIT: I ended up just adding another folder to Foo's project and moving the contents of Bar's project to this folder. I am then able to do `HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Bar/Bar's Default.aspx")` I'd still love to hear a better solution than this, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/csweb/Default.aspx")`. The tilde "~" in your current redirect says to start in this application's home folder. By removing that you can redirect to some other location on your site.

You can also fully qualify the redirect to go to an entirely different site if you wish.

Comment: @Jim Hey, thanks for the response. I tried this and it takes me to the same url as using the tilde. I am wondering how my solution could tell the difference between Foo's Default.aspx and Bar's Default.aspx. Clearly they have to be in different locations in the directory structure -- but I am not seeing any signs of being inside of "Foo" and how to navigate to the "Bar" side of the directory structure.

Comment: @Sean. Hey, sorry, I may not of read your OP carefully enough the first time. So, Foo's default page is at /csweb/Default.aspx. Where is Bar's page then? /csweb/bar/Default.aspx? It can't be in the same folder or it would be over written, right? If it is in /csweb/bar/, then add /bar to your redirect.

Comment: @Jim So, the directory structure inside of Visual Studio is Solution -> [ (Project Foo) | (Project Bar) ] with various files underneath each. If I right click Project Foo, go to properties, web, and specify the virtual path as "/csweb/" it causes Project Foo to start up as localhost:port/csweb/Foo's Default Page. I set Project Bar's virtual path in the same way in order to keep the root directory structure identical. I expected to be able to access Project Bar's files somehow, but only seem to be able to when I indicate that Project Bar is the start-up project.

Comment: @Sean. Ah, I think I am beginning to understand now. I am just used to using IIS projects (old-school). You are probably using a Web App project where there is a little "web server" icon down in your system tray. Is that correct?  If so, each of your projects is starting its own mini web server, each with its own port (http://localhost:50001/csweb/...) where my arbitrary ***50001*** is a port number, different for each project.  If that's the case I don't think they will ever find each other. If that's not the case, then let's discuss some more.

Comment: Yep. That's the case.. and that's kinda what I came to the conclusion of, as well. :) See my edit above. Thanks for spending some time looking at this with me, I'm glad we came to the same conclusion.

Comment: @Sean, Good luck with that.  You also need to consider how both those websites will deploy together without stepping on each other too (if you were to leave them in the same folder).

Comment: I know this is old post but I had the same situation described by Sean Anderson.  My redirect wasn't working when deployed on server (for other users) when written like this: "HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://servername/MyVBApp/MyCSharpApp/Page1.aspx")" but when I changed it to this: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/MyVBApp/MyCSharpApp/Page1.aspx") it started working.  I also had 2 projects within 1 solution, but configured as a single startup project in the solution properties (VS 2008).  This keeps cutting off h t t p : slash slash  servername portion of my example