# How to combine two projects in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

I am having two different websites and I want to access the second website's home page as a link in the first website. But I am getting the problem in merging them in visual studio(2008). And also what to do with two **web.config** files.
I had also tried to copy all the files of second project in the first project but it doesn't work out.
what are the possible ways to merge two websites.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the two websites in separate VisualStudio projects within a single VisualStudio solution or you could put the second website in a folder within the first project and do:

```
HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/ProjectB/PageInProjectB.aspx");


<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkLink" runat="server"
NavigateUrl="~/ProjectB/PageInProjectB.aspx"> Link </asp:HyperLink>
```

where ProjectB is the new folder in the first project.

See [Response.Redirect from one web project to another in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669159/response-redirect-from-one-web-project-to-another-in-visual-studio)

You can only really have one web.config in a project. You *can* have more but these are usually used for different publishing environments, for example a dev and live deployment. (dev is used for testing stuff and live is the actual site people use)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9ats98.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk4ahe0t(v=vs.90).aspx

EDIT: I also suggest you checkout http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials to get more familiar with Visual Studio and ASP.NET Web Forms.